# Real time dashboards in Power BI

Tags: rest, powerbi

In Power BI you have the functions of Power BI REST API to insert rows in your dataset and have live dashboards. The problem with that feature is updating an existing row. There is no UPDATE command in POWER BI REST API.
There is a DELETE Command but it deletes the whole table data and if you have a table with about 500.000 rows, this is not an option.
To implement real time dashboards, I need some kind of UPDATE command or a workaround. Does anybody have an idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Test your requests here : http://www.requestmaker.com/ 
The UPDATE works by simply sending the updated records only.

Initial dataset:
[
{
 "code" :1,
 "name" :"City1",
 "value" :78
},
{
 "code" :2,
 "name" :"City2",
 "value" :85
}
]

Update dataset:
[
{
 "code" :2,
 "name" :"City2",
 "value" :85
}
]

Comment: Update dataset: [ { "code" :2, "name" :"City2", "value" :80 } ]

Comment: Have you tried this in Power BI Service? Power BI has specific Uri for adding rows and how does the Uri for update look like?

Comment: Use the same PowerBI Service URI to update , but send only the records you are updating with the new values. The first column of the dataset should be the identifier.

Comment: I found something that I didn't realize myself. Each record has a lifespan. You need to update it every 60 seconds. You can update as many as you want per request, but you need to keep them all 'fresh'.

Comment: I have tried, what you said. Sent the same URI for an existing record below 60 seconds and also after 60 seconds. It does not update the exisiting record, but creates a new record with the same identifier. Can you please share your running code?